# Solving integral related to second moment of normal distribution restricted to interval. CAS answer acceptable

Tags: calculus, probability, normal-distribution

Let $f(x)=\frac{1}{\sigma\sqrt{2\pi}}\, e^{-\frac{(x - \mu)^2}{2 \sigma^2}}$, the pdf of the 1-dimensional normal distribution.

Is it possible to compute $\int_{-a}^a x^2 \frac{1}{\sigma\sqrt{2\pi}}\, e^{-\frac{(x - \mu)^2}{2 \sigma^2}}dx$?

In other words we're looking at the concentration of the second moment.

I'm happy to know the answer for the case where $\mu=0$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can perform the change of variable: $x-\mu=y$, then
$$
\begin{eqnarray}
\frac{1}{\sigma\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-a}^a x^2 e^{-\frac{(x - \mu)^2}{2 \sigma^2}}dx&=&
\color{#00f}{
\frac{1}{\sigma\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-a- \mu}^{a- \mu} y^2 e^{-\frac{y^2}{2 \sigma^2}}dy}+\\&+&
\color{#0a0}{
\frac{2\mu}{\sigma\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-a- \mu}^{a- \mu} ye^{-\frac{y^2}{2 \sigma^2}}dy}+\\&+&
\color{#f00}{\frac{\mu^2}{\sigma\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-a- \mu}^{a- \mu}e^{-\frac{y^2}{2 \sigma^2}}dy}.
\end{eqnarray}
$$
The last one is  computed (directly by the definition) in terms of [error functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_function):
$$\color{#f00}{\frac{\mu^2}{\sigma\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-a- \mu}^{a- \mu}e^{-\frac{y^2}{2 \sigma^2}}dy}=\frac{\mu ^2 }{2}\left(\text{erf} \left(\frac{a-\mu}{\sqrt{2} \sigma} \right)+\text{erf}\left(\frac{a+\mu}{\sqrt{2} \sigma} \right)\right)$$
The second integral can be computed via change of variable: $y^2=t$ (and get a simple exponential integral):
$$
\color{#0a0}{\frac{2\mu^2}{\sigma\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-a- \mu}^{a- \mu}y e^{-\frac{y^2}{2 \sigma^2}}dy}=
\frac{\mu^2}{\sigma\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{(a+ \mu)^2}^{(a- \mu)^2}e^{-\frac{t}{2 \sigma^2}}dt=\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi }} \mu  \sigma  \left(e^{-\frac{(a+\mu )^2}{2 \sigma ^2}}-e^{-\frac{(a-\mu )^2}{2 \sigma ^2}}\right)
$$
The first one can be handled in different ways. For example, one can assume a differentiation under the integral. One can set $\frac{1}{\sigma^2}=\alpha$:
$$
\int_{-a- \mu}^{a- \mu} y^2 e^{-\frac{\alpha \ y^2}{2}}dy=-2\int_{-a- \mu}^{a- \mu}\frac{\partial e^{-\frac{\alpha \ y^2}{2}}}{\partial \alpha}dy=-2\frac{\partial}{\partial \alpha} \int_{-a- \mu}^{a- \mu} e^{-\frac{\alpha \ y^2}{2}}dy.$$
And the last-mentioned integral was already computed in terms of error functions. Then just use the differentiation of error functions, perform the back substitution ($\alpha=\frac{1}{\sigma^2}$) and do not forget about the multiplier $\frac{1}{\sigma\sqrt{2\pi}}$ and you are ready to collect the result:
$$\!\color{#00f}{\frac{1}{\!\sigma\sqrt{2\pi}}\!\int_{-a- \mu}^{a- \mu}\! y^2 e^{-\frac{y^2}{2 \sigma^2}}dy\!}=\!
\frac{\sigma ^2}{2}\!\!\left(\!
\text{erf}\!\left(\!\frac{\!a+\mu \!}{\sqrt{2} \sigma }\!\right)\!+\!\text{erf}\!\left(\!\frac{a-\mu }{\sqrt{2} \sigma }\!\!\right)
\!\!\right)\!-
\!\frac{\!\sigma\! }{\sqrt{2 \pi }}\!\left(\!\!
(a-\mu ) e^{-\frac{(a-\mu )^2}{2 \sigma ^2}}\!+\!(\!a\!+\!\mu\!) e^{-\frac{(a+\mu )^2}{2 \sigma ^2}}\!
\right).\!
$$

Comment: are you still in process? I see that both the last and second integrals are zero when the mean is zero. And then you are left with an integral which is the same as the first, in the case where the mean is zero.

Comment: @EricGregor now you have all the parts to collect the complete solution.